# Can I use a Y-harness to charge battery while in use?

Tags: batteries, connector, parallel, charging

I’m a beginner in creating circuits, and I need to find a way to charge a battery while the battery is powering a motor on another circuit.

I’m planning on using a parallel circuit, with one end of a dean connector/y harness connected to the motor, while the other is connected to the charger, with the female end connected to the battery.

Will the setup work? Or will the currents clash or some other effect will occur?

Connector I’m using:

[image]

Like [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WHPD4KD) but costlier:

Comment: The beginning of creating a circuit is to actually draw a circuit diagram and not post pictures that are meaningless technically. Of course, you may work for Amazon and want to create a cheap ad.

Comment: You need to include links to the manufacturer's datasheets for the battery, the charger, and the motor.

Comment: @Andyaka That IS a circuit diagram :-).

Answer (score 1):

This will "tend to work" in most cases.

In some cases the load may be such as to cause the charger to undervoltage cutout or to go into a slow trickle up mode - but probably not if the battery voltage is kept withing usual operating range.

---

Using that adaptor for its stated purpose would be risky.
Paralleling two high energy batteries could result in death of the adaptor, possibly one or both batteries and just possibly the connection maker if they were in different enough states of charge.

If the price is in Singapore dollars it is very excessive.

A suitably edited photo can be useful
A link would be a good idea.

Comment: Very/too smart chargers may have trouble detecting end of charge and throw you an error message. Overall should work though.